# how to create last file with renaming messages where message batch size is not greater than equal to 240

Tags: c#

In below application,

1. `Producer` method adding messages to a `blocking` collection.
2. In `Consumer` method, I'm consuming `blocking` collection and adding `messages` to a `list` and when size >= 240, writing that list to json file.

At some point I don't have any new messages in `blocking` collection, but in `Consumer`, I have a list of messages which is not >=240 in size, then in this case  , the app is not able to write to a new JSON file (rest of the data).

How can I let the  `Consumer` know that no new messages coming up, write whatever left with you in a new file?

**Is this possible? let say `Consumer` will wait for 1 minute and if there is no new messages, then write whatever left in an new file?**

Here is the code (here I'm adding 11 messages. Till 9 messages the batch size is 240 and it's generates a file, but message no 10 & 11 not able to write in new file),

```
class Program
{
    private static List<Batch> batchList = new List<Batch>();
    private static BlockingCollection<Message> messages = new BlockingCollection<Message>();

    private static int maxbatchsize = 240;
    private static int currentsize = 0;
    private static void Producer()
    {
        int ctr = 1;
        while (ctr <= 11)
        {
            messages.Add(new Message { Id = ctr, Name = $"Name-{ctr}" });
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            ctr++;
        }
    }

    private static void Consumer()
    {
        foreach (var message in messages.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            var msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

            Console.WriteLine(msg);

            if (currentsize + msg.Length >= maxbatchsize)
            {
                WriteToFile(batchList);
            }

            batchList.Add(new Batch { Message = message });
            currentsize += msg.Length;
        }
    }

    private static void WriteToFile(List<Batch> batchList)
    {
        using (StreamWriter outFile = System.IO.File.CreateText(Path.Combine(@"C:\TEMP", $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")}.json")))
        {
            outFile.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(batchList));
        }

        batchList.Clear();
        currentsize = 0;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Producer());
        var consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Consumer());
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Supporting classes,

```
 public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Batch
{
    public Message Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this possible? let say Consumer will wait for 1 minute and if there is no new messages, then write whatever left in an new file?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
class Program
    {
        private static readonly List<Batch> BatchList = new List<Batch>();
        private static readonly BlockingCollection<Message> Messages = new BlockingCollection<Message>();

        private const int Maxbatchsize = 240;
        private static int _currentsize;

        private static void Producer()
        {
            int ctr = 1;
            while (ctr <= 11)
            {
                Messages.Add(new Message { Id = ctr, Name = $"Name-{ctr}" });
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                ctr++;
            }
            Messages.CompleteAdding();
        }

        private static void Consumer()
        {
            foreach (var message in Messages.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                if (_currentsize >= Maxbatchsize)
                {
                    var listToWrite = new Batch[BatchList.Count];
                    BatchList.CopyTo(listToWrite);
                    BatchList.Clear();
                    _currentsize = 0;
                    WriteToFile(listToWrite.ToList());
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    if (Messages.IsAddingCompleted)
                    {
                        var remainSize = Messages.Select(JsonConvert.SerializeObject).Sum(x => x.Length);
                        if (remainSize == 0)
                        {
                            var lastMsg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
                            BatchList.Add(new Batch { Message = message });
                            _currentsize += lastMsg.Length;
                            Console.WriteLine(lastMsg);
                            var additionListToWrite = new Batch[BatchList.Count];
                            BatchList.CopyTo(additionListToWrite);
                            BatchList.Clear();
                            _currentsize = 0;
                            WriteToFile(additionListToWrite.ToList());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                var msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
                BatchList.Add(new Batch { Message = message });
                _currentsize += msg.Length;
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
            }
        }

        private static void WriteToFile(List<Batch> listToWrite)
        {
            using (StreamWriter outFile = System.IO.File.CreateText(Path.Combine(@"C:\TEMP", $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")}.json")))
            {
                outFile.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listToWrite));
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Producer());
            var consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Consumer());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not able to compile it. `batchList.Copy()` & `listToWrite.Length`

Comment: Is this possible? let say I will wait for 1 minute and if no further messages, then write  , whatever left in a new file?

Comment: could you please describe the logic?

Comment: Thanks @NaDeR Star, but it's not working. Generates only 1 file (till size limt) and 2 messages (9 and 10) still not writing to new file

Comment: Thanks, it's partial working. If there ONLY 1 message remaining in blocking collection after writing file for previous result, then this message not able to write in a new file, but if there are more than 1 message then loop will run and then `remainSize == 0` conditin satisfied

Comment: Just let the code runing, break points and tracing may change functionality in multi thread jobs. I will check the code again.